# What is the best way to fit classification variables in linear regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, multiple-regression

I'm trying to build a model for a dataset that looks like this:

[image]

I builded one using just the non-classification variables (**age**, **bmi** and **child**), but the predictions are not accurate. How can i fit the classification variables (**sex**, **smoker** and **region**) into the model? I tryied to just convert them and normalize but it doesn't seems to work

Comment: By 'classification variables', do you mean [categorical variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable)? You can [dummy encode](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)) them.

Comment: See the tag [tag:categorical-encoding] (and maybe add it!)

Comment: Yeah, this solves the problem. I made the dummy encode with 'sex', 'region' and 'smoker', one hot encoding the first two and this solved the problem. Ty